# How to deploy Celery worker on DigitalOcean App Platform

Tags: redis, django-celery, digital-ocean-apps

I am trying to add celery + redis to my django app hosted on DO App Platform. I understand there is an issue I need to work around that is documented here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/is-there-an-issue-with-celery-on-app-platform

My problem is that I cannot even get to that point. Django celery and celery beat is working fine locally i.e. I can schedule and run background tasks.
I start the celery worker using:

```
celery -A my_project.celery worker -l info
```

And the celery beat worker using:

```
celery -A my_project beat -l info
```

I cannot figure out how to do this on DO App platform.

A couple of tutorials simply say you need to create a worker in DO. What exactly does this mean? Don't I just need to run these commands somehow? Do I need another virtual environment or will the worker use the same one from my django app (like it does when run locally). When I try to create a worker on DO it wants me to create another app.

Could anybody point me to an example of how all of this is supposed to work?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You cannot directly do this on the digital ocean server for a lot of reasons, u need to use a supervisor to start, monitor and restart the celery service.
I assume u are using redis as your message broker so u can ssh into ur server and start by running the command below

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install redis-server
redis-cli ping
```

After entering the last command the console should output `PONG`
This is to ensure redis is up and running.

**NEXT PHASE**
Now u need to install a supervisor that will monitor, start, stop or restart any service u want on your server, and in this case the service we care about is celery_worker and celery_beat.
So run the command below to install the supervisor

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

When the installation is complete run the command below

```
sudo service supervisor status
```

And you should get an ouptut like this

```
supervisor.service - Supervisor process control system for UNIX
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-05-19 15:27:28 UTC; 1min 16s ago
     Docs: http://supervisord.org
 Main PID: 592 (supervisord)
   CGroup: /system.slice/supervisor.service
           └─592 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

May 19 15:27:28 djangobin-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Supervisor process control system for UNIX.
May 19 15:27:28 djangobin-ubuntu supervisord[592]: 2018-05-19 15:27:28,830 CRIT Supervisor running a
May 19 15:27:28 djangobin-ubuntu supervisord[592]: 2018-05-19 15:27:28,831 WARN No file matches via 
May 19 15:27:28 djangobin-ubuntu supervisord[592]: 2018-05-19 15:27:28,847 INFO RPC interface 'super
May 19 15:27:28 djangobin-ubuntu supervisord[592]: 2018-05-19 15:27:28,847 CRIT Server 'unix_http_se
May 19 15:27:28 djangobin-ubuntu supervisord[592]: 2018-05-19 15:27:28,848 INFO supervisord started
```

Now ensure u are in the root directory ( u can check by running `ls` and u should see directories like this `bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  sys  tmp  usr`).
In the root directory u will create your configuration file with the command below

```
echo_supervisord_conf > ./djangobin.conf
```

Use the command below to move the new file to the supervisor directory

```
sudo mv djangobin.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
```

Use the command below to open the file

```
nano /etc/supervisor/conf.d/djangobin.conf
```

This file contains a lot of content and sections but we don't need all for what we want to do so you have to delete all except the section name `[supervisord]`.
After removing the irrelevant sections the file should now look like this

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
```

Next we are going to add the programs we want supervisor to monitor
so u can copy and paste the content below

```
[program:celery_worker]
command=/home/your_user/venv/bin/celery -A project worker -l info
directory=/home/your_user/django_project
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery.out.log


[program:celery_beat]
command=/home/your_user/venv/bin/celery -A project beat -l info
directory=/home/your_user/django_project
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery_beat.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery_beat.out.log
```

- "your_user" here refers to the user u created on your ubuntu server that has right to ur django project
- "project" here refers to your app folder that directly contains the settings.py and wsgi.py file
- "django_project" here refers to your project folder that contains all your source code
- "venv" is the name of the virtualenv u created

now save and close this file
Then run the command below

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
```

You should get an output like this

```
celery_beat: available
celery_worker: available
```

Then run

```
 sudo supervisorctl update
```

You should get an output like this

```
celery_beat: added process group
celery_worker: added process group
```

Any time u make changes to the `djangobin.conf` file run the above two commands

Now check that celery is now running with the command below

```
sudo supervisorctl status
```

You should get an output like this

```
celery_beat                      RUNNING   pid 6027, uptime 1:44:03
celery_worker                    RUNNING   pid 6028, uptime 1:44:03
```

You can output the celery_worker log to the console like you have on the development server with the command below

```
tail celery_worker stderr
```

Now anytime your start, stop or restart your server the supervisor will always ensure that all ur celery services are up and running

**THE END**

I used the article below as a reference for this and you can refer to it too https://www.codementor.io/@overiq/deploying-django-project-to-digitalocean-xt5s538tp

Comment: Unfortunately, DigitalOcean's App Platform is a managed service, so it does not offer root access to the server for this to work.

Comment: So to make chron jobs you have to get a server up an running? What a pain

Answer (score 0):

### Running Django's Server, Celery Worker, and Celery Beat on 3 components within a single Digital Ocean App Platform instance

In order to run the server, celery worker, and celery beat I create 3 instances within Digital Oceans App Platform.

All 3 instances share the same environmental variables and run the same Github repo.  When I push to github they all deploy at the same time.  Because they're all in the same app platform instance if one fails to build the entire project rolls back to the last stable deployment.

#### Steps

Create a single App Platform instance with one component running your desired Github repo, grant permissions to digital ocean.  Once created edit the App Spec to include 3 instances.  The "server" as a `service`, "celery worker" and "celery beat" as `workers`.

To edit the App Spec go to App Platform -> Click Your Project -> Click Settings -> Make sure "App" is selected under components -> Scroll down to App Spec -> Click "Edit"

You can copy my App Spec below and update it to include your project name, Github address, and environmental variables.

This configuration requires 3 servers and costs around $49/ month in 2023 - The celery instance requires a larger server with 2gb of ram as it will consume 1.5gb at steady state. (The build fails if the instance is too small)

I also have a managed Postgres and managed redis instance that I have created separately in Digital Ocean and have connected to Django within my Django files `settings.py` and `.env`. These each cost $15/ month.

This brings the total configuration to $79/ month.

### Digital Ocean App Spec

```
alerts:
- rule: DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
- rule: DOMAIN_FAILED
domains:
- domain: api.XXXXXXXXXXX.com
  type: PRIMARY
envs:
- key: DATABASE_URL
  scope: RUN_AND_BUILD_TIME
  value: postgresql://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@[DIGITAL OCEAN DB PATH].ondigitalocean.com:[PORT]/[DB NAME]?sslmode=require
- key: REDIS_URL
  scope: RUN_AND_BUILD_TIME
  value: rediss://default:[PASSWORD]@[DIGITAL OCEAN DB PATH].ondigitalocean.com:[PORT]
features:
- buildpack-stack=ubuntu-22
ingress:
  rules:
  - component:
      name: web
    match:
      path:
        prefix: /
name: prod-backend-v1
region: nyc
services:
- github:
    branch: master
    deploy_on_push: true
    repo: [YOUR_ORGANIZATION]/extrovert_django_backend
  http_port: 8080
  instance_count: 1
  instance_size_slug: professional-xs
  name: web
  run_command: gunicorn --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm extrovert.wsgi
workers:
- environment_slug: python
  github:
    branch: master
    deploy_on_push: true
    repo: [YOUR_ORGANIZATION]/extrovert_django_backend
  instance_count: 1
  instance_size_slug: professional-s
  name: celery-worker
  run_command: celery -A extrovert worker --loglevel=info
  source_dir: /
- environment_slug: python
  github:
    branch: master
    deploy_on_push: true
    repo: [YOUR_ORGANIZATION]/extrovert_django_backend
  instance_count: 1
  instance_size_slug: professional-xs
  name: celery-beat
  run_command: celery -A extrovert beat
  source_dir: /
```

### Django settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config() # Will Pull from ENV Variable "DATABASE_URL"
}

REDIS_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')
```

### Django .env

These values can be included in the App Spec on Digital Ocean or in `.env` for running locally.

These urls can be found in Digital ocean under
Databases -> Click your Database -> Overview -> Connection Details -> Dropdown -> Connection String -> Click to Show Password -> Copy Entire String.

```
export DATABASE_URL='postgresql://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@[DIGITAL OCEAN DB PATH].ondigitalocean.com:[PORT]/[DB NAME]?sslmode=require'
export REDIS_URL='rediss://default:[PASSWORD]@[DIGITAL OCEAN DB PATH].ondigitalocean.com:[PORT]'
```